# Running Ubuntu on multiple systems using the same bootable USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb, bootloader

I recently switched to Ubuntu Linux after getting frustrated with Windows. I installed Ubuntu on a USB and mostly use Ubuntu.

But I have multiple machines and use all of them and want to take all my progress on Ubuntu with me but I could not load Ubuntu on my other devices because I don't have grub boot loader on them.

Is there any way to boot Ubuntu without the grub boot loader?

Comment: I would install the `grub` boot loader on your thumb-drive, and use the device fn key (which various on make & model) to have it ask which drive you want to boot, and use it that way.  It works for me, but you didn't provide release details, and how it boots does vary by machine/model (mainly which key is needed, or of it's possible as some machines have boot from thumb-drives disabled for security reasons).

Comment: Step by step instructions for a Full install to USB including on board GRUB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-19-10-to-usb-device-step-by-step

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. Instead of trying to boot without the grub bootloader, make a system that has the grub bootloader in the USB drive. Do you need booting both in BIOS mode and UEFI mode? It is somewhat more difficult, but possible too. In that case I think it is best to start from the beginning, create all relevant partitions etc.